# Aggregating data between two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, aggregate

So I have two tables that I need to aggregate data by.

The first looks like this:

```
zip code | key
x          1
x          2
x          3
y          4
y          5
```

The second looks like this:

```
characteristics | key
a                 1
b                 1
c                 1
d                 2
e                 2
f                 3
g                 4
```

and I need to join them to look like this...

```
zip code | key | characteristics

x          1     a
x          1     b
x          1     c
x          2     d
x          2     e
x          3     f
y          4     g
...        ...   ...
```

I can't quite think of what the correct subqueries / joins would be to make this happen. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 USING (key)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

<strike>select table1.zipCode, table1.key, table2.characteristics 
    from table1
    inner join table2 on table1.key = table2.key</strike>

Ok... 
Then try this.

```
select t1.zipcode, t1.keys, t2.character
from table_1 t1
full outer join Table_2 t2 on t1.keys = t2.keys
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Rwiti. With this query I only get characteristics joined on one key per multiple zip codes, and there are multiple keys per zip.

Comment: Great! I don't think MySQL likes full outer joins so I just used this to emulate one:

SELECT * FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id

and it worked. thank you!

Comment: ohh .. I wrote and tested this query on MS SQL Server 2012. Anyways, glad it helped.